# Caret not shown in empty iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I am trying to implement my own rich text editor using iframe. However, whenver I click inside the empty rich text editor, the caret or mouse cursor doesn't show up. After checking on google, I found that we need to add some html to the iframe beforehand such as 'break tag. But my code below will only add the break tag to the first rich text editor and not to the second. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.......

```
$.fn.createRichTextEditor = function(width,height="auto") {
    var iframeDocument;

    var iframeDocumentId = this.attr("id") + "-rte-editor";

    var newHtml =   "<div id='rte-" + iframeDocumentId + "' class='rte'>" +
                    "<ul class='rte-toolbar'>" +
                    "<li id='bold'><button id='rte-boldBtn-" + iframeDocumentId + "' class='rte-button' value='bold' title='Bold'></button></li>" +
                    "<li id='italic'><button id='rte-italicBtn-" + iframeDocumentId + "' class='rte-button' value='italic' title='Italic'></button></li>" +
                    "<li id='underline'><button id='rte-underlineBtn-" + iframeDocumentId + "' class='rte-button' value='underline' title='Underline'></button></li>" +
                    "<li id='createLink'><button id='rte-createLinkBtn-" + iframeDocumentId + "' class='rte-button-link' value='createLink' title='Link'></button></li>" + 
                    "<li id='unlink'><button id='rte-unlinkBtn-" + iframeDocumentId + "' class='rte-button-link' value='unlink' title='Unlink'></button></li>" + 
                    "</ul>" +
                    "<iframe class='rte-iframe' id='" + iframeDocumentId + "' frameBorder='0'></iframe>" +
                    "</div>";

    this.after(newHtml);
    this.css('display', 'none');

    var iframe = document.getElementById(iframeDocumentId);
    var rte = iframe.parentElement;
    $(rte).css('width', width);
    $(rte).css('border', '1px solid #ccc');

    $(iframe).on('load', function() {
        $(iframe).width("100%");
        $(iframe).height(height);
        iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument;    
        iframeDocument.designMode = 'On';
        $(iframeDocument).find('body').html('<br><br/>');

    });

};
```

Comment: You don't need the load Event since the iframe doesn't have a source + you need to focus on the iframe window. Here is a working demo: [https://jsfiddle.net/j1p2m692/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/j1p2m692/2/)

Comment: Does not work. Cannot even edit anything if remove the load

Comment: Indeed, it dosesn't work on Firefox ! here is another example, is working on both Chrome & Firefox [https://jsfiddle.net/d98mhv0s/](https://jsfiddle.net/d98mhv0s/)

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH This was helpful. Can you put this as answer, so I can upvote it and choose as answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each matching element in your plugin:

```
$.fn.createRichTextEditor = function (width, height) {

    this.each(function () {

        // Your code for each element here

    });

});
```